# Javascript + PHP $_POST array empty

Tags: php, javascript, http-post

While trying to send a POST request via `xmlhttp.open("POST", "url", true)` (javascript) to the server I get an empty `$_POST array`.

Firebug shows that the data is being sent. Here is the data string from Firebug: `a=1&q=151a45a150...`. But `$_POST['q']` returns nothing.

The interesting thing is that `file_get_contents('php://input')` does have my data (the string above), but PHP somehow doesn't recognize it. Tried both $_POST and $_REQUEST, nothing works.

Headers being sent:

```
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401        Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://website.com/
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the correct Content-Type header. This is necessary for POST requests:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Answer (score 2):

Send a

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

header instead of `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "script.php", true);
xmlhttp.send("foo=bar&answer=42");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spent hours trying to find a fix for this very problem.

I made the idiotic mistake of concatenating several strings which I wanted to be the parameters, and THEN calling `encodeURIComponent` on the whole lot. This of course meant that

```
foo=bar&this=that
```

became

```
foo%3Dbar%26this%3Dthat
```

which of course is gibberish to a PHP script. While I doubt there can be many people who would do something as silly as this, I hope it saves someone the headache I just gave myself....